Event in Vega specification is evaluating to to the wrong value when it is False
I am making a modification to this Vega code. I have made
a modification and added a field called DCOUNT_ID. It is a distinct count that flexes based on the number of tasks in the result set.
When I filter in PowerBI for example to a specific task, the DCOUNT_ID shows the value '1' in the Data table, removing those filters sets the DCOUNT back to 18.
The problem is when I have filtered to 1 task for the condition, it should update the yRowHeight to 40 but it instead updates to 20.
This is what I have tried
{
      "name": "yRowHeight",
      "value": 30,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "dblclick",
          "update": "datum.DCOUNT_ID <= 2 ? 40:20",
          "force": true
        }
      ]
    }

